# Is there a way to set a required number of reviewers per pull request as opposed to per branch in GitHub?

Tags: github

Currently, all pull requests in a certain branch require a certain number of reviewers, as in this example: https://github.blog/2018-03-23-require-multiple-reviewers/

Is there a way to change the required number of reviewers on a per-PR basis as opposed to the entire branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not seem possible, and the [GitHub API for creating a pull request](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls/pulls#create-a-pull-request=) certainly does not expose the number of reviewer as a potential parameter.

Similarly, [changes to a pull request branch](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/working-with-forks/allowing-changes-to-a-pull-request-branch-created-from-a-fork) does not involve changing the number of reviewers.